# How to call multiple hosts using RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

Consider two hosts host1= "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employee/id" and host2="http://localhost:8081/springrestexample/student/id".
I want to call these hosts using single RestTemplate. First i want to call host1 and after that if any error code related to service unavailable is returned then i want to call host2. Thank you.

```java
private static void getDetails()
{
    final String host1 = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/employee/id";

    final String host2 = "http://localhost:8080/springrestexample/student/id";


    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(host1, String.class);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resttemplate throws an exception when some error occurred.

The easiest way could be::

```
try {
   restTemplate.getForObject(host1, String.class);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
   restTemplate.getForObject(host2, String.class);
   ...
}
```